# gitlab ci access to private snippets

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a snippet that I want to use in my gitlab ci across multiple projects.

```
before_script:
 - curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/snippets/1
 - bash my_script.sh
```

I tried using the `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` resulting in a 401. Is there a way to gain access without creating a user token?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is NO.
`CI_JOB_TOKEN` variable used for authenticating with the GitLab Container Registry and downloading dependent repositories [1].
You can create personal and project Snippets, with three visibility levels [2], **private**, **internal** and **public**.

Private snippets are only visible to the snippet creator, so you need a Personal access token (with **api** scope!!!, and it's not recommended for CI jobs in public/shared projects.

Suggestion:

- Create an Internal snippet
- Create a user for CI jobs, with read-only access to project (e.g. ci-bot).
- Do CI jobs with **ci-bot**'s Access Token.

[1] https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html
[2] https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/snippets.html

Comment: CI_JOB_TOKEN can also be used to trigger other pipelines and is used for temporary access to clone the repo (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#syntax-of-environment-variables-in-job-scripts).